# Restrict elements inside an array to be a specific type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to restrict elements inside an Array to be of certain type. However, typescript allows me to mix them up and won't complain.

Find below a simple example in which typescript allows me to add a pear to the apples array. It won't let me add an apple to the pears, though.

```
type Pear = {
  color: string;
  isOrganic: boolean;
};

type Apple = {
  color: string;
};

const pear: Pear = {
  color: "green",
  isOrganic: true,
};

const apple: Apple = {
  color: "red",
};

const apples: Apple[] = [apple, pear];
const pears: Pear[] = [apple, pear];
```

I also tried the following:

```
type Apple = {
  color: string;
  isOrganic?: never;
};
```

But I don't think this is the right way. Intellisense keeps telling me there is a property isOrganic every time I type a . after an apple. Also, when creating an apple it tells me I can fill that property.

Why is this happening and how could I achieve what I want in a clean way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the key things to understand about TypeScript is that its type system is **structural** (based on the shape of the type), not nominal (based on the name of the type). `Pear` is an `Apple` to TypeScript, because anything with a `color` property is a `Apple` to TypeScript. (If the thing has other properties as well, that just makes it a subtype of `Apple`, but a subtype is a valid instance of its supertype, so....). You can fix in this case by adding a property (often called `__type__`) that uses a string literal value (`__type__: "Apple"`) vs. (`__type__: "Pear"`).

Comment: [Playground example](https://tsplay.dev/NnaMdw). Note that making `__type__` optional works in *this* case, but there are use cases (not least inheritance) where it wouldn't.

Comment: I understand... I was trying to avoid adding a __type__ as well, for I thought there may be a way using only type signatures.

Comment: Well, for your use case above, you can with the optional `__type__` thing (see the playground) which although it's in the type doesn't mean it has to be in the objects. But without that, you can't do it, because the structures match otherwise.